# React-Native State Dynamic Color

Tags: image, dynamic, colors, react-native, state

I want to set the `tintColor` of my png `Image` dynamic. Currently I try to set the color via the `state` property and change the value with `setState`

My code is something like this (Expect that everything works fine above and around the following code snippet):

```
class dynamicImageColor extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myDynamicColor: '#ffffff'
    }
  }

  changeColor(bool) {
    this.setState({
      myDynamicColor: bool ? '#932727' : '#ffffff';
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Image source={myPNGImage} style={styles.PNGImageStyle}/>
    )
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  PNGImageStyle: {
    tintColor: this.state.myDynamicColor,
    width: 25,
    height: 25
  }
}
```

Everything in the code above is working fine if i set the tintColor static. And the function changeColor(bool) is called in some other place which is not relevant and works fine.

My actual problem is that i get the error message:

**undefined is not an object(evaluating'this.state.myDynamicColor**

I also wanted to see if there are wrong values transported anyhow. But the console showed the right `'#ffffff'` hex_code format at the `myDynamicColor`

I dont know further and help would be very nice. Also i would be glad if you show me a better solution :)

Thank you
BR
Jonathan

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First your styles var can't use `this` because it's not part of the class. Second the value of tintColor would not be automatically updated. render() would always use the same styles variable.

What you want to do is this (notice the square brackets):

```
render() {
  return (
    <Image source={myPNGImage} style={[styles.PNGImageStyle, {tintColor: this.state.myDynamicColor}]}/>
  );
}
```

and

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  PNGImageStyle: {
    width: 25,
    height: 25
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint that i am not in my class. This absolutely was my problem :) Completely didn´t see it. Thanks a lot, your solution works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Pass the props to the component and use them in props of image component like below :

```
<Image
    style={{
        tintColor: props.color,
        resizeMode: "contain",
        height: 100,
        width: 200
    }}
    source={require(props.imageSrc)}
/>
```