# Building a Tic-Tac-Toe Game in React Native adding Styles

Tags: react-native

I am building a tic-tac-toe game and need to know how I can add an individual style to an individual board piece. If I am using state, would I need a variable that represents each piece on the board? Is there more of an elegant way of doing this. I posted my code here, just give you an idea on how it looks.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { ListView, StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

    class MainApp extends Component {

      state = {
          clicked: true,
          spacePlayed: [],
          tables: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
          playedSpace: [],
        }

      searchBoard = (index) => {}

      _setBoard = (tableId) => {
          this.setState({
              clicked: !this.state.clicked,
            });
          var spacePlayed = this.state.playedSpace.push(tableId);
          this.setState({ spacePlayed });

        }

      buildBoard = () => {
          var clicked = false;
          return (this.state.tables.map((table, index) => {
              if (index === 0) {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this._setBoard(index)}>
                            <View style={styles.table}></View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                );
              } else {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this._setBoard(index)}>
                            <View style={styles.tableActive}></View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                );
              }
            }));

        }

      render() {
        const active = this.state.clicked
            ? styles.active
            : null;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                    {this.buildBoard()}
                </View>
        );

      }

    }
    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {

            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            width: 200,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginLeft: 70,
            marginTop: 20,

          },
        table: {
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#78BEC5',
            margin: 5,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          },
        active: {
            backgroundColor: '#ECAF4F',
          },
        tableActive: {
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#ECAF4F',
            margin: 5,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          },

      });
    export default MainApp;
```

Comment: I see two options:
- Either you set up a new function wich returns you either a table or table active component.
- Or you are setting the backgroundColor (or more styles) into the code by state:
-> Example: <View style={[styles.exampleStyle, {backgroundColor: this.state.yourBackgroundColor}]}/>

Comment: The second answer refers to following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792362/react-native-state-dynamic-color